# Font Awesome 5 not working when adding icon through ::before

Tags: html, css

I am trying to include font awesome icon through CSS pseudo elements, but it never appears.
I already tried to set the font family to "Font Awesome 5 Free", "Font Awesome 5 Brand" and adjust font weights to different values but none of them work for me. What did I miss?

**My CSS**

```css
.form-field::before{
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
    content: "\f057";
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 40px;
    z-index: 200;
}

.form-field::after{
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f057";
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 40px;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

**CDN**

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Check Rendered Fonts in your styles Computed tab (browser code inspector), be sure that proper font is rendered

Comment: Can you please add some reproducible HTML

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the input element does not support pseudoelements (::before, ::after). Add wrapper and assign your styles to wrapper

Comment: Thank you Vlad, I did use pseduoelements on a input and my problem is gone after the fix. :)

Comment: @MaxwellYu well, I've added a working example anyway, you can upvote it if it was helpfull :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working example

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper::before{
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
    content: "\f057";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 40px;
    z-index: 200;
}

.wrapper::after{
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f057";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 0;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 40px;
    z-index: 200;
}

input {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="form-field" type="text">
</div>
```